# Jquery Plugin for tables that allow accordion like expanding and filtering of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I am looking to create a table of data that allows the following:

- Click able rows that expand like an accordion to display text.
- A filter function: when the user clicks a link at the top of the page some of the rows disappear. Ideally it would be similar to the photography portfolio pages that animate to show certain categories of pictures.

Any guidance would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Accordion functionality can be achieved with Bootstrap's COLLAPSE feature:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Having filters would normally have to be accomplished through a database-driven application where defining characteristics are recorded as attributes in the table. My recommendation is PHP/MySQL. This presents a steep learning curve, but you can start making static pages with bootstrap right away, and even code multiple pages, one for each filter so the "filter" is actually just a hyperlink to a page that only displays those rows.